# Large tables going beyond margins

Tags: tables, margins

I am new to LaTeX and now trying to generate a table with the following code. Even with all the fixes that I gathered from this site, I don't get the perfect table the margin width has increased but the `\hline` goes only till the original margins on the right side. I would really appreciate any help.

```
\begin{table}[htbp]%
\footnotesize%
\centering%
\caption{\textbf{Impact of policy on psychosocial outcomes (ITT estimates)}}
\noindent
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\textwidth minus \textwidth}}l c c c c c c c c@{}}


 \hline \hline

  &(1)& (2)&    (3)&    (4)&    (5) &   (6) &   (7) &   (8) \\
         \multicolumn{1}{c}{{Variables}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{{Self-efficacy}}  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{{Peer support}} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{{School experience}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{{Teacher support}}\\
         \hline

Treatment  & 0.115** & 0.117** & 0.031 & 0.035 & 0.036 & 0.036 & -0.023 & -0.017 \\
& (0.048) & (0.049) & (0.045) & (0.046) &     (0.047) & (0.048) &   (0.045) &   (0.045) \\
Age(in years) & & 0.092** & & 0.016 & & 0.020 & & 0.050 \\
& &  (0.038) & & (0.038) & & (0.037) & & (0.035) \\
Gender(boy=1) & & -0.074 & & 0.022 & &      0.014 & &       -0.001 \\
& &  (0.052) & & (0.051) & & (0.049) & & (0.048) \\
Scheduled Caste & & -0.139* & & -0.115 & & 0.071 & & -0.141 \\
& &  (0.074) & & (0.070) & & (0.060) & & (0.066) \\
Muslim & & -0.251*** & & 0.072 & & 0.013 & & 0.083 \\
& &  (0.063) & & (0.064) & & (0.059) & & (0.062) \\
Mothers education & & 0.016** & & 0.004 & & -0.001 & & 0.012* \\
& &  (0.007) & & (0.007) & & (0.006) & & (0.006) \\
Working Mother & & -0.008 & & -0.032 & & -0.093 & & 0.001 \\
& &  (0.066) & & (0.066) & & (0.063) & & (0.061) \\
Asset index & & -0.008 & & -0.009 & & -0.002 & & -0.015** \\
& &  (0.008) & & (0.008) & & (0.008) & & (0.007) \\
Number of rooms in house & & 0.000 & & -0.010 & & -0.019 & & 0.018 \\
& & (0.025) & & (0.024) & & (0.028) & & (0.022) \\
Constant & -0.058 & -0.802** & -0.015 & -0.128 & -0.018 & -0.786** & 0.012 & -1.098*** \\
& & (0.036) & (0.311) & (0.037) & (0.307) & (0.307) & (0.325) & (0.036) & (0.331) \\
Observations & 1553 & 1534 & 1577 & 1556 & 1585 & 1564 & 1557 & 1537 \\
R-squared & 0.003 & 0.071 & 0.000 & 0.122 & 0.000 & 0.159 & 0.000 & 0.173 \\

\hline
\hline
\multicolumn{9}{p{0.99\textwidth}}{\footnotesize  Notes: *** $p \geq 0.01$, ** $p \geq 0.05$, * $p \geq 0.1$. Regression in columns 1, 3, 5, 7, and 9 are univariate models regressing outcome variable on treatment. Regressions in columns 2, 4, 6, 8, and 10 have sub-district dummies and controls. Standard errors are clustered at the pair level in all models to account for pairwise matching design.. The dependent variables, test scores, are standardized z-scores; hence, the coefficient estimate is the effect size. Gender, Scheduled Caste, Muslim and working mother are indicator variables. Age, asset index, mother’s education (in years) and number of rooms in the house are continuous.}
\end{tabular*}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/5764)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try replacing `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}` with `\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth} ` .

Comment: Please always provide compilable code we can use to reproduce the problem. Why do you think your table won't fit on **my** standard page size? Without a complete minimal example, the table may well fit for some of us and not others. The same is true of any answer - it may fit the table here, but not for you.

Answer (score 0):

I just redesigned your table. With a small trick, not only the `changewidth` environment is not necessary anymore but also the table's font size can be `normalsize`.

For better number-column alignment, I suggest using type `S` `siunitx` column and `tabularx`. Note that the `multirow` cell notion is just applied to handle the long variables of the column `i`:

[image: improved table]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{ \multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]%
\caption{\textbf{Impact of policy on psychosocial outcomes (ITT estimates)}}
    \sisetup{input-symbols = {( - )},
             table-space-text-post={(},
             table-align-text-post=false,
             table-format=-1.3}
%    \small%
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
%\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
                            l
                            S[table-space-text-post={**}]
                            S[table-space-text-post={***}]
                       *{3}{S[table-space-text-post={)}]}
                            S[table-space-text-post={**}]
                            S[table-space-text-post={)}]
                            S[table-space-text-post={***}]
                           @{}}
    \toprule
Variables   & \mcc{Self-efficacy}       & \mcc{Peer support}
            & \mcc{School experience}   & \mcc{Teacher support} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
    \cmidrule(lr){8-9}
            & \mcx{(1)} & \mcx{(2)}     & \mcx{(3)} & \mcx{(4)}
            & \mcx{(5)} & \mcx{(6)}     & \mcx{(7)} & \mcx{(8)} \\
    \midrule
Treatment   & 0.115**   & 0.117**   & 0.031     & 0.035
            & 0.036     & 0.036     & -0.023    & -0.017    \\
            & (0.048)   & (0.049)   & (0.045)   & (0.046)
            & (0.047)   & (0.048)   & (0.045)   & (0.045)   \\
    \addlinespace
Age(in years)
            &           & 0.092**   &           & 0.016
            &           & 0.020     &           & 0.050     \\
            &           &  (0.038)  &           & (0.038)
            &           & (0.037)   &           & (0.035)   \\
    \addlinespace
Gender(boy=1)
            &           & -0.074    &           & 0.022
            &           & 0.014     &           & -0.001    \\
            &           & (0.052)   &           & (0.051)
            &           & (0.049)   &           & (0.048)   \\
    \addlinespace
Scheduled Caste
            &           & -0.139*   &           & -0.115
            &           & 0.071     &           & -0.141    \\
            &           &  (0.074)  &           & (0.070)
            &           & (0.060)   &           & (0.066)   \\
    \addlinespace
Muslim      &           & -0.251*** &           & 0.072
            &           & 0.013     &           & 0.083     \\
            &           &  (0.063)  &           & (0.064)
            &           & (0.059)   &           & (0.062)   \\
    \addlinespace
Mothers education
            &           & 0.016**   &           & 0.004
            &           & -0.001    &           & 0.012*    \\
            &           &  (0.007)  &           & (0.007)
            &           & (0.006)   &           & (0.006)   \\
    \addlinespace
Working Mother
            &           & -0.008    &           & -0.032
            &           & -0.093    &           & 0.001     \\
            &           &  (0.066)  &           & (0.066)
            &           & (0.063)   &           & (0.061)   \\
    \addlinespace
Asset index &           & -0.008    &           & -0.009
            &           & -0.002    &           & -0.015**  \\
            &           &  (0.008)  &           & (0.008)
            &           & (0.008)   &           & (0.007)   \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{28mm}{Number of rooms in house}
            &           & 0.000     &           & -0.010
            &           & -0.019    &           & 0.018     \\
            &           & (0.025)   &           & (0.024)
            &           & (0.028)   &           & (0.022)   \\
    \addlinespace
Constant    & -0.058    & -0.802**  & -0.015    & -0.128
            & -0.018    & -0.786**  & 0.012     & -1.098*** \\
            &           & (0.036)   & (0.311)   & (0.037)
            & (0.307)   & (0.307)   & (0.325)   & (0.036) \\%& (0.331)
    \midrule
Observations& {1553}    & {1534}    & {1577}    & {1556}
            & {1585}    & {1564}    & {1557}    & {1537}    \\
R-squared   & 0.003     & 0.071     & 0.000     & 0.122
            & 0.000     & 0.159     & 0.000     & 0.173     \\
    \bottomrule
\multicolumn{9}{p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}{\footnotesize
Notes: *** $p \geq 0.01$, ** $p \geq 0.05$, * $p \geq 0.1$.

Regression in columns 1, 3, 5, 7, and 9 are univariate models regressing outcome variable on treatment. Regressions in columns 2, 4, 6, 8, and 10 have sub-district dummies and controls. Standard errors are clustered at the pair level in all models to account for pairwise matching design.. The dependent variables, test scores, are standardized z-scores; hence, the coefficient estimate is the effect size. Gender, Scheduled Caste, Muslim and working mother are indicator variables. Age, asset index, mother’s education (in years) and number of rooms in the house are continuous.}
\end{tabularx}
%\end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```